# Need help about datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have datagrid(see bellow) there is columns with date time how i can make background red where rooomNumer is 777 from 1/8/2011 to 5/8/2011 with code behind? Room number column bind with observable collection

```
 ObservableCollection<RoomsInfoData> _RoomsInfoCollection = new ObservableCollection<RoomsInfoData>();
        public RoomsInfo()
   public ObservableCollection<RoomsInfoData> RoomsInfoCollection
        {
            get { return _RoomsInfoCollection; }
        }

        public class RoomsInfoData
        {
            public string RoomType { get; set; }
            public string RoomNumber { get; set; }
            public string RoomStatus { get; set; }
        }
HProDataContext db = new HProDataContext();
            var _RoomNumber = (from d in db.SelectRooms select d.roomnumber).ToList();
            var _RoomType = (from d in db.SelectRooms select d.roomtype).ToList();
            var _RoomStatus = (from d in db.SelectRooms select d.status).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < _RoomNumber.Count; i++)
            {

                _RoomsInfoCollection.Add(new RoomsInfoData { RoomNumber = _RoomNumber[i], RoomType = _RoomType[i], RoomStatus = _RoomStatus[i] });
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Code behind is not the right way to do this. You should be using styles and triggers for this

Comment: thanks advice but i dont know how to do that this is why im trying to do it wrong way

Comment: it impossible to make it red from code behind/

Comment: Are you creating columns in XAML or are you auto generating them?

Comment: no im creating it from code behind and auto generating is off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that

1. "this" refers to your window or user control in which this data grid is placed.
2. this.dataGrid refers to your datagrid in which you have added columns from code behind.

We will specify a style in the Window / UserControl's Resources collection ... like this

```
    <UserControl.Resources> <!-- could be Window.Resources if datagrid lies in a Window -->
            <Style x:Key="RoomNumberValidationCellStyle"
                       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}"> <!-- DataGridCell because we need to apply this style to specific columns -->
                    <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=RoomNumber}" Value="777">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

in code behind after you set all columns to this.dataGrid ... do this...

```
    foreach(var col in this.dataGrid.Columns)
    {
            var headerText = (string)col.Header;
            if (headerText == "1/8/2011" || headerText.Header == "2/8/2011"
            || headerText.Header == "3/8/2011" || headerText.Header == "4/8/2011"
            || headerText.Header == "5/8/2011")
                    col.CellStyle = this.FindResource("RoomNumberValidationCellStyle") as Style;
    }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks. i dont even have enough words to say how much im grateful. I have one question :) Does it possible to transfer room number collection? for example if in grid is room numbers: 777, 104, 213. and i only want to make background red on 104 room . so how i can modify this parto of trigger? >>> Value="777" and then how transfare collection from code behind? thanks again.

Comment: For that you can only do one thing. You will have to create another property in your RoomInfo class... say IsRoomMatched. 
This property must be set to True by your code based on your room number criteria 
e.g. if you want 777 to be red then make IsRoomMatched true for 777 or if you want 104 to be red then make IsRoomMatched true for that room. 
Then modify your trigger to check IsRoomMatched as True... like this... 
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsRoomMatched}" Value="True"> .....

 Dont forget to raise INotifyPropertyChanged in the setter of the IsRoomMatched.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Style x:Key="RedRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PropertyName}" Value="777" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Just replace PropertyName with the property in the ViewModel where the value will be 777 and apply to the proper rows.

Comment: `ViewModel`?How do you know `Acid` is using `MVVM`?

Comment: i dont use mvvm i will add some simple codes in my question please take look

Comment: I reed bind. Mi mind relate it directly to MVVM although this time fails the guess.